# Show questions with the appropriate layout based on type (text, checkbox, select, etc) is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form for a user create custom questions. For that the user needs to introduce the question (ex: Receive notifications?) and also the type of field (text, long text, checkbox, select menu, radio button). If the user selects a field of checkbox, select menu or radio button he also need to introduce the available options for the question.

In the database the questions are inserted in the questions and question_options tables like:

//questions table

```
id     question                    type          conference_id      
1       question1                 text                 1
2       question2                long_text             1   
3       question3                checkbox              1  
4       question4                radio_btn             1  
5       question5                select_menu            1
```

//question_options table:

```
id     question_id                   type                
1       3                             q3op1       
2       3                              q3op2
3       4                             q4op1 
4       4                              q4op2 
5       5                              q5op1      
6       5                              q5op2
```

My doubt is how to show properly in the registration.blade.php the inputs (text, radio button, checkbox, select, textarea and input file) based on the type stored in the column "type" of the questions table. For now is not working properly it is appearing like the left screen of the image but should appear like the right screen of the image:

[image]

Do you know why is not appearing like the right screen of the image?

In the Question model there is this getHtmlInput method():

```
  switch ($this->type) {
            case "text":
                  return "<input type='text' name='$name' val='$val' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . "/>";
            case "checkbox":
                return "<input type='checkbox' name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . "/>";
            case "radio_btn":
                return "<input type='radio' name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . "/>";
            case "select_menu":
                return "<select name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . "></select>";
            case "textarea":
                return "<textarea name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . "></textaera>";
        }
```

In the registration.blade.php  the questions are presented with the code below:

```
@if ($allParticipants == 0)
    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
            {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
            'participant_question[]',($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") ? 'required' : '',
            $class = "form-control",
             $customtype=$customQuestion->type) !!}
        </div>
        @if($customQuestion->hasOptions())
            @foreach($customQuestion->options as $option)
                <p>{{ $option->value }}</p>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

QuestionController store method to create question:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'question' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'type' => 'required|max:255|string',
    ]);
    $conference = Conference::find($id);
    $question = Question::create([
        'conference_id' => $conference->id,
        'question' => $request->question,
        'type' => $request->type,
    ]);


    if(in_array($request->type, Question::$typeHasOptions)){
        foreach($request->input('questionOptions') as $questionOption) {
            QuestionOption::create([
                'question_id' => $question->id,
                'value' => $questionOption
            ]);
        }
    }
    Session::flash('success', 'Question created with success.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Models:

// Question model

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'type', 'conference_id',
    ];

    public static $typeHasOptions = [
        'radio_btn',
        'select_menu',
        'checkbox'
    ];

    public function ticket_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TicketType', 'ticket_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }

    public function options() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionOption');
    }


    public function hasOptions() {
        return in_array($this->type, self::$typeHasOptions);
    }

    public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $val = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype=false)
    {
        switch ($this->type) {
            case "text":
                  return "<input type='".($customtype?:"text")."' name='$name' val='$val' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . ">";
            case "checkbox":
                return "<input type='".($customtype?:"checkbox")."' name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . ">";
            case "radio_btn":
                return "<input type='".($customtype?:"radio")."' name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . ">";
            case "select_menu":
                return "<input type='".($customtype?:"radio")."' name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . ">";
            case "textarea":
                return "<input type='".($customtype?:"radio")."' name='$name' class='$class''" . ($required?:"required") . ">";
        }
    }


}
```

// QuestionOption model

```
class QuestionOption extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'question_id', 'value' ];

    public function question() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected your page and see how the html is formed? I suspect some issues with your quotes, missing quotes or extra quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistakes in your code:

- In `getHtmlInput` were set quotes twice `class='$class''"`
- In `getHtmlInput` 3 last inputs in `switch` had `($customtype?:"radio")`
- All inputs generated with `name[]`, but `[]` need only for `radio` and `checkox`
- In `registration.blade.php` printed input and once and in options cycle just printed value `<p>{{ $option->value }}</p>`
- Using `<label for="participant_question">` make no sense in this case, because it should bound to input with unique id.

Each input should have unique `name` field. You need to add `name` field to `questions` table. And use in template as `$customQuestion->name`

**Examples of fixed code (not tested):**

```
registration.blade.php
```

May look like this:

```
@if ($allParticipants == 0)
@foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            {{$customQuestion->question}}
        </div>
        <div>
            @if($customQuestion->hasOptions())
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    $customQuestion->options,
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type) 
                !!}
            @endif
        </div>        
    </div>
@endforeach
@endif
```

and method `getHtmlInput()`

May look like this:

```
public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype=false)
{
    $html = '';
    $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='$name' class='$class' ".($required?:" required").">" : '';


    foreach($options as $option) {
        switch ($customtype) {
        case "text":
            $html .= "<div><input type='text' name='$name' value='".$option->value."' class='$class'" . ($required?:" required") . "></div>";
            break;
        case "checkbox":
            $html .= "<div><input type='checkbox' name='".$name."[]' value='".$option->value."' class='$class'" . ($required?:" required") . ">". $option->value."</div>";
            break;
        case "radio_btn":
            $html .= "<div><input type='radio' name='".$name."[]' class='$class'" . ($required?:" required") . "> ".$option->value."</div>";
            break;
        case "select_menu":
            $html .= "<option value='".$option->value."'>";
            break;
        case "textarea":
            $html .= "<div><textarea name='$name' class='$class'" . ($required?:" required") . ">" . $option->value . "</textarea></div>";
            break;
    }
    }

    $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why the inputs are appearing below the text and not side by side? Like: https://ibb.co/kqZkNd.

Comment: And I didn't understand this part about the <label for="participant_question"> can you explain better? Are you saying that this should be removed?

Comment: And here "'.$name .'[]'" appears an error "Cannot use [] for reading". The name appears with name "" like "<div class="form-group">
<label for="participant_question">Receive Notifications?</label>
        
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Yes" class="form-control" 1="">Yes</div>

        <div><input type="checkbox" name="" value="No" class="form-control" 1="">No</div>
        
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">
</div>".

Comment: 1. This can be caused by styles: if in styles set display:block; for inputs, then they will be on a separate line. Or it may be, because of wrapping input/text in tags like `<p>` or `<div>`.

Comment: 2. Tag `label` usually using to select bounded radio/checkbox input by clicking on label's text. They are bound by input's id attribute. Like this: <input id="example-id"> <label for="example-id">example text</label>. So when you don't use labels for unique input's, it make no sense, because they are using to activate single unique radio/checkbox.

Comment: 3. You right, if use $name[] inside string, it it will lead to error. The right version is: "text ".$name."[] text".

Comment: Thanks, the generated HTML is like this "https://jsfiddle.net/tbf0e1ce/". The name is an empty array. So when the user selects some option and clicks go to step 2 it appears always a validation error saying that the fields are required.

Comment: Instead of " name='".$name."[]'" maybe should be " name='"participant_question[]'?

Comment: If you will use same name with array (`name[]`) for different groups of inputs, then you can't identify in php handle script, what input bound to array item.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why in the case of a custom question is the type of select menu the select menu don't appear? Only radio buttons and checkboxes appear, the text area and input type text also don't appears.

Comment: Check `$customtype` variable inside `getHtmlInput` method. Most likely it not equal to switch cases.

Comment: It seems that is "checkbox".

Comment: The generated html for select is "  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Select menu question</label>
    <option value="opt1"></option><option value="opt1">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">
    </option></div>".

Comment: Change `$customtype == 'select'` to `$customtype == 'select_menu'` before and after switch. Updated answer, you can get code from there.

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears "<select name="participant_question" class="form-control" 1=""><option value="opt1"></option><option value="opt2"></option></select>". It only appears the value it dont appears any text on the option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172355/discussion-between-johnw-and-zen).